# "Run-time error '287': Application-defined or object-defined error" while using CurrentItem.Saveas or CurrentItem.HTMLBody in Outlook 2016

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2016

We have an Access database running under Office 2010.

We have to change to Office 365 and get

> Run-time error '287': Application-defined or object-defined error

with:

```
Dim olAppSaida As Outlook.Application
Dim olItemSaida As Outlook.MailItem

Set olAppSaida = CreateObject("Outlook.application")

Set olItemSaida = olAppSaida.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

If Not TypeName(olItemSaida) = "Nothing" Then
    olItemSaida.SaveAs "C\TEstes\" & strProcesso & ".Msg", olMSGUnicode
End If
```

The reference to Outlook XX.X library is checked. The error occurs in the line:

```
olItemSaida.SaveAs "C\TEstes\" & strProcesso & ".Msg", olMSGUnicode
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

It was all about Security Policies for Outlook 2016.

Now the code runs like it ever did.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As @mariodcm says, the problem is related to Security Policies. He pointed me to the solution. To make long history short:

*Found out that it was blocked by the following policy:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\security\promptoomsend*

*The key was set to 0 = Automatically Deny. Changing the key to 2 = Automatically Approve solved the problem.*

More information:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/office-365-proplus-word-vba-sending-or-saving-mail/5654cfb4-9671-4900-aec4-93ee06e62c40

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the path string is correct.
2. Try to specify another type to save with - `OlSaveAsType`.
3. It may be a security issue when automating Outlook from an external application. See ["A program is trying to send an e-mail message on your behalf" warning in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/3189806/a-program-is-trying-to-send-an-e-mail-message-on-your-behalf-warning-i) for more information.