# How to add an html signature to Outlook message from Access with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

Code posted here and been reported to work, doesn't work for me.

This code throws

> Run Time Error '287 Application-defined or object defined error

on the line `Signature = Outmail.body`.

I want the default signature for the current Outlook user.

```
Private Sub Command33_Click()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim currentDate As Date
Dim DeliveryDate As String
Dim Recipients As String
Dim CarbonCopy As String
Dim Signature As Variant

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

currentDate = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
Recipients = "a@gmail.com"
CarbonCopy = "b@gmail.com"
Signature = OutMail.Body

'msg hasn't been defined so it's commented out. msg in the body has been replaced with "msg".
'msg = "<span style='color:black'><p>Dear Team,</p>"

'msg = msg & "Thank you in advance</span>"

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    'Capture signature block.
    .Display
    Signature = .HTMLBody
    .To = Recipients
    .CC = CarbonCopy
    .Subject = "PSR " & currentDate
    .HTMLBody = "<span style = 'color:#1F497D'>" & "msg" & "</span>" & Signature
    .Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.FullName
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57204574/102937

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add default signature in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994116/how-to-add-default-signature-in-outlook)

Comment: The solutions in the suggested threads do NOT work.  They also fail on the line for setting Signature variable = Outmail.body, or some variation thereof.

Comment: Remove that line. I don't think you can access the body before the `.Display` line. Your code works for me. You're correctly setting the value of `Signature = .HTMLBody` just below the `.Display` line and therefore, do not need `Signature = OutMail.Body`

Answer (score 0):

As stated, remove `Signature = OutMail.Body`.

Then put a break point after `Signature = .HTMLBody`, and inspect its value.

This is what I do in Outlook 365 (it also worked in Outlook 2010):

```vb
' Outlook HTML: after Mailitem.Display, .HtmlBody starts with
' <p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
' Exactly in this line we want to put our HTML encoded mail text.
oItem.HtmlBody = Replace(oItem.HtmlBody, "&nbsp;", strMyBody, Count:=1)
```

The default signature is below this line, and remains unchanged.

Edit: `our HTML encoded mail text` means: I pass plain text to my function, and replace `vbCrLf` by `<br>`.

If you have actual HTML with `<p>` and so on, use [Jeremy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64898999/3820271) instead.

Comment: Inspection of value with break point as you suggested shows Signature = Empty.  The signature is there though, but disappears the moment this line runs: .HTMLBody = "<span style = 'color:#1F497D'>" & "msg" & "</span>" & Signature

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` to see what's going on.  @MichaelRousseau

Answer (score 0):

If removing the line `Signature = OutMail.Body` doesn't work try the `WordEditor` approach. Each mail item has a word editor which is simply a word document. It is much easier to work with than generating your own html. You can also simply copy and paste (even excel ranges) and all formats will be preserved.

```
Private Sub Command33_Click()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim currentDate As String
    Dim DeliveryDate As String
    Dim Recipients As String
    Dim CarbonCopy As String
    
    Dim EmailMsg As String
    EmailMsg = "msg"
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    currentDate = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    Recipients = "a@gmail.com"
    CarbonCopy = "b@gmail.com"
    
    EmailMsg = "Dear Team," & Chr(10) & "Thank you in advance"
        
    With OutMail
        .To = Recipients
        .CC = CarbonCopy
        .Subject = "PSR " & currentDate
        .Display
        
        With .GetInspector.WordEditor
            .Range(0, 0).Text = EmailMsg
            .Range(0, Len(EmailMsg)).Font.TextColor = RGB(31, 73, 125)
        End With
        
        ' display the generated html body in the immediate window
        ' remove after testing
        Debug.Print .HTMLBody
        
        .Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.FullName
    End With
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Also note `Format()` returns a string and therefore, `currentDate` should be a string (not a date)

Comment: Thanks, but the code you posted also throws a Run Time Error 287.  This time on With .GetInpector.WordEditor.  Could it be a Reference that I need to check besides Word 16.0 Object library?

Comment: You're using late binding so you don't need any particular reference. Is your outlook set up properly? Try to create a new message manually in outlook and send it. See if any message box comes up. Keep your outlook application running and try executing the code again

Comment: Thanks Super Symmetry.  I wish it were something as simple as that.  Outlook is set up properly, a new message created in Outlook brings the default signature with no issues.

Comment: "Application-defined or object defined error" is VBA's way of telling you that outlook is complaining and I don't know why. So sometimes performing the same steps manually highlights the actual issue. 2 more suggestions: (1) Try to run this code from within outlook - open outlook and press Alt+F11. (2) Try to send some test emails using word's mail merge. The first might give you a more specific error and the second might reset something that was causing the issue.